# Rendering 2 queries into 2 separate tables in pdf in php

Tags: php, mysql

I have code which is supposed to render my query data from mysql database into pdf. I want the data to be displayed in 2 tables in the same pdf. My code is doing all that but its rendering the tables as one without space between the 2 tables. How can I separate these tables?

Here is how the tables are being rendered:
[image]

Here is my code:

```
<?php

    if
        (
            isset($_GET["pdf"]) &&
            isset($_GET['payment_request_id'])
        )
    {
        require_once 'pdf.php';
        include('database_connection.php');
        include('function.php');
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        $output = '';
        $statement = $connect->prepare
            (
                "
                    SELECT
                        *
                    FROM
                        tbl_payment_request
                    WHERE
                        payment_request_id = :payment_request_id
                    LIMIT 1
                "
            )
        ;
        $statement->execute
            (
                array
                    (
                        ':payment_request_id'       =>  $_GET["payment_request_id"]
                    )
            )
        ;
        $result = $statement->fetchAll();
        foreach($result as $row)
        {
            //Payment Details Table Rendering ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            $output .=
                '
                    <table width="100%" border="1" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0">

                        <tr>
                            <th>Payment Description</th>
                            <th>Vehicle Reg</th>
                            <th>Ref Number</th>
                            <th>Amount</th>
                        </tr>
                '
            ;
            $statement = $connect->prepare
                (
                    "
                        SELECT
                            *
                        FROM
                            tbl_payment_details
                        WHERE
                            payment_request_id = :payment_request_id
                    "
                )
            ;
            $statement->execute
                (
                    array
                    (
                        ':payment_request_id'       =>  $_GET["payment_request_id"]
                    )
                )
            ;
            $payment_details_result = $statement->fetchAll();
            $count = 0;
            foreach($payment_details_result as $sub_row)
            {
                $count = $count + 1;
                $output .=
                    '
                            <tr>
                                <td>'.$sub_row["payment_description"].'</td>
                                <td>'.$sub_row["reg_number_id"].'</td>
                                <td>'.$sub_row["ref_number"].'</td>
                                <td>'.$sub_row["ref_amount"].'</td>
                            </tr>
                    '
                ;
            }

            $output .=
                '
                    <br/>
                    <br/>
                    <br/>
                '
            ;

            //Cost Sharing Table Rendering ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            $output .=
                '
                    <table width="100%" border="1" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0">

                        <tr>
                            <th>CRS/Site</th>
                            <th>Protocol</th>
                            <th>Budget Class</th>
                            <th>Amount</th>
                        </tr>
                '
            ;

            $statement = $connect->prepare
                (
                    "
                        SELECT
                            *
                        FROM
                            tbl_cost_sharing
                        INNER JOIN
                            tbl_crs_site ON tbl_crs_site.crs_site_id = tbl_cost_sharing.crs_site_id
                        INNER JOIN
                            tbl_protocol ON tbl_protocol.protocol_id = tbl_cost_sharing.protocol_id
                        LEFT JOIN
                            tbl_funding_source ON tbl_funding_source.funding_source_id = tbl_protocol.funding_source_id
                        INNER JOIN
                            tbl_budget_class ON tbl_budget_class.budget_class_id = tbl_cost_sharing.budget_class_id
                        WHERE
                            payment_request_id = :payment_request_id
                    "
                )
            ;
            $statement->execute
                (
                    array
                        (
                            ':payment_request_id'       =>  $_GET["payment_request_id"]
                        )
                )
            ;
            $cost_sharing_result = $statement->fetchAll();
            $count = 0;
            foreach($cost_sharing_result as $sub_row)
            {
                $count = $count + 1;
                $output .=
                    '
                            <tr>
                                <td>'.$sub_row["crs_site_name"].'</td>
                                <td>'.$sub_row["protocol_name"].'</td>
                                <td>'.$sub_row["budget_class_name"].'</td>
                                <td>'.$sub_row["cost_sharing_amount"].'</td>
                            </tr>
                    '
                ;
            }

        }
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        $pdf = new Pdf();
        $file_name = 'PRF#'.$row["payment_request_id"].'.pdf';
        $pdf->loadHtml($output);
        $pdf->render();
        $pdf->stream($file_name, array("Attachment" => false));
    }

?>
```

Comment: does a `<p></p>` between the tables help?

Comment: as the last time show a $output

Comment: I have put this ```<p></p>``` but it's not changing

Comment: how do I show $output?

Comment: echo $output or print $output

Comment: The most important skill in debugging, and indeed all of programming, is Break The Problem Down. It makes no difference whether this data comes from a database, and what query string parameters you're processing, and all the rest of the noise you've left in your question. Your actual question is "how do I render a PDF, using this particular PHP library, that has two tables separated by whitespace", and the [mcve] for that question would be much shorter than what you show here.

Answer (score 0):

I have finally resolved it by replacing this part of the code;

```
            $output .=
                '
                    <br/>
                    <br/>
                    <br/>
                '
            ;
```

with

```
            $output .=
                '
                    </table>
                    <br/>
                '
            ;
```

Comment: So your actual problem was that you were generating invalid HTML (not closing your table correctly). This would have been much more obvious if your code was structured better: first, fetch the data from the database; then, perform calculations with it if necessary; then, format that data into HTML.